# Compare value of rows in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know if the values in two different rows of a Dataframe are the same.
My df looks something like this:

```
df['Name1']:
Alex,
Peter,
Herbert,
Seppi,
Huaba

df['Name2']:
Alexander,
peter,
herbert,
Sepp,
huaba
```

First I want to Apply .rstrip() and .toLower(), but these methods seem to only work on Strings. I tried `Str(df['Name1']` which worked, but the comparison gave me the wrong result.

I also tried the following:

```
    df["Name1"].isin(df["Name2"]).value_counts())
    df["Name1"].eq(df["Name2"]).value_counts())
```

Problem 1: I think `.isin` also returns `true` if a Substring is found e.g. `alex.isin(alexander)`would return true then. Which is not what I´m looking for.

Problem 2: I think `.eg` would do it for me. But I still have the problem with the `.rstrip()` and `to.lower()` methods.

What is the best way to count the amount of same entries?

Comment: `df['Name1'] == df['Name2']` will return a Series of `True/False` whether the respective entries are identical. Is this what you want?

Comment: what's your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print (df)
     Name1      Name2
0     Alex  Alexander
1    Peter      peter
2  Herbert    herbert
3    Seppi       Sepp
4    Huaba      huaba
```

If need compare each row:

```
out1 = df["Name1"].str.lower().eq(df["Name2"].str.lower()).sum()
```

If need compare all values of `Name1` by all values by `Name2`:

```
out2 = df["Name1"].str.lower().isin(df["Name2"].str.lower()).sum()
```

Comment: It worked for me, although I could have gotten to this myself. Yet simple and elegant. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Use set to find the common values between two dataframe columns

```
common_values = list(set(df.Name1) & set(df.Name2) )
count = len(common_values)
```